# Filter Org Mode Note by Date

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am using Emacs Org Mode to keep tracking what I do. When I want to make a weekly report I would like to see what was going on for this week.

There are notes for each headings with C-c C-z, so all nodes have timestamp. How can I see all the notes in a file with given time range?

When I find clock report, I could put :block lastweek so I could see how much time was used for each tasks. What I want is to see all the notes. There must be a function for this. I just couldn't find it easily. Could you help?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to use a deadline or scheduled string to represent your note date, which would then open up an entire world of sorting and display options?  You can even change the word deadline or scheduled -- e.g., `(setq org-deadline-string "NOTE-ONE:")` or `(setq org-scheduled-string "NOTE-TWO:")`.  Org-mode is not designed to sort notes by date.

Comment: @lawlist, that's unfortunate. Org is very good TODO tool and sometimes people would like to see what I've done for a week. Even if I couldn't finish, I may have some progress. Maybe it would be better for me to write a simple script to filter them.

Comment: Here is a sample `elisp` regexp to get you started:  `\\(- Note taken on \\)\\[\\([^]]+\\)\\]\\( \\\\\\\\\\)`  You may wish to take a look at functions similar to `org-agenda-get-deadline` to borrow some ideas when writing your own script.  I don't see how this project could be solved with *a simple script to filter* -- be prepared to spend a considerable amount of time working on it.

Comment: What I mean simple script is an Awk script that reads an Org file. But I found a workaround for state messages, not notes. I could M-x org-agenda a to open Org Agenda and then v l to see logs. I can v L to see all logs. Then I can just grep it with 'State:'. And it's macro-able. But it's not notes, it's just state change message...

Comment: It doesn't show the notes you can filter out items with an inactive timestamp in the last week using `org-agenda`.  Do a tags query (`C-c a m` with the default keybindings and search for `TIMESTAMP_IA>"<-1w>"`.  Maybe there's some way to filter this down to just items with notes?